# InAppSettingsKit with multiple localizations

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I'm using InAppSettingsKit in my iPad app, including localized Strings for English, German and Japanese. Everything works just fine, but I would like to be able to switch languages in-app, and this does not seem to be supported by InAppSettingsKit. Here's my showSettings method:

```
// show the inapp settings view
-(void) showSettings
{
  IASKAppSettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  settingsViewController.delegate = self;
  settingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;

  UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsViewController];

  [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
}
```

so the settings VC is recreated every time, but appears to re-use the language selection from the initial app start.

The user's language selection is written both to my private "language" setting in `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` as well as the "AppleLanguages" array.

Where/how is the old language information cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard behavior of iOS and usually you shouldn't aim to change it. You could probably change it using the AppleLanguages key (or some other key) in NSUserDefaults but AFAIK the current language is always static after app launch.

Comment: Thanks, after some more digging around I believe that this is due to NSBundles being cached after the initial load, and there does not seem to be a way to invalidate this cache.